# JSFViewState ID session scoped?

Tags: jsf-2

We have JSF2.1.7 in our app deployed in weblogic 10.3.7 ,we have the default **state_saving_method to  server**.

Our security could sucessfully perform the below test..

```
Session 1 
   1)  Access the login page 
   2) Post the login request with successful login.
   3) record the login form values along with ViewStateId.

Session 2
   1) Access the login page
   2) Post the login request with form values including view state id from session 1.
   3) successful login  (but expected view expired as it is different session).
```

The Viewstate id can be used only within one session is proved incorrect with server state saving method.

But is it not the viewstate stored against the session id in the server ? ,is there anyting in our settings missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'd say this is working as designed. The `javax.faces.ViewState` (in the case of `SERVER` state saving mode) object is designed to preserve the condition of the page being viewed in a session and uses the `viewStateId` as a key to map to the object on the server side. As per JSF implementation, there is a fixed number of view state objects that can be saved per session. If a client attempts to postback a `viewStateId` that cannot be matched with a key in the `StateManager`or found anywhere for the given session, JSF will presume that the key might have been present at some point and has simply expired, hence the `ViewStateExpiredException`

Comment: So the javax.faces.ViewState is a session scoped value , our issue is how the viewstateid in one session can be used in other ?

Comment: @user684434 If I read your question correctly, when you attempted to use the same view state Id in another session, it failed, correct? That is the expected behavior as the context is not required to verify whether or not the same view state id has been used in another session. Once the viewstateId cannot be found in the current session, the context simply assumes that the view state Id might have been attached to that session previously, but has been removed for any number of reasons

Comment: No , successful login  (but expected view expired as it is different session). It should have thrown ViewExpired Exception.

Comment: @user684434 But the login is a fresh request for the post-login page. So the viewstate ID you passed could quite possibly have been ignored. ViewState id is only valid for use with repeat requests i.e. a view that has been previously rendered and then is being resubmitted. Try reusing a viewstate id from another session in a postback from a page that has already been rendered. Look at [this article](http://www.developersbook.com/jsf/jsf-tutorials/jsf-tutorials.php) for a good explanation on the restore view jsf phase and the use of viewstate.